# Rails 3.2: includes/eager_load/preload a has_many association with through and conditions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In order to make some queries more efficient, am trying to eager-load a `has_many :through` association that has conditions based on the main table. I've got:

```
class Scope
   has_many :bought_diamonds, class_name: 'Diamond'

class ScopeCache
   belongs_to :scope
   has_many :bought_diamonds, :through => :scope
```

I need `ScopeCache#bought_diamonds` to have a condition based on `diamonds.created_at` and `scope_caches.snapshot_date`.
Here's some things I've tried and the errors I got:

**Option 1:**

```
has_many :bought_diamonds, :through => :scope, conditions: 'diamonds.created_at >= DATE_SUB(scope_caches.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and diamonds.created_at < scope_caches.snapshot_date'
```

Problems:

```
ScopeCache.includes(:bought_diamonds).last
# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'diamonds.created_at' in 'where clause': SELECT `scopes`.* FROM `scopes`  WHERE `scopes`.`id` IN (34) AND (diamonds.created_at >= DATE_SUB(scope_caches.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and diamonds.created_at < scope_caches.snapshot_date)

ScopeCache.eager_load(:bought_diamonds).last # OK
ScopeCache.eager_load(:bought_diamonds).last.bought_diamonds # OK
ScopeCache.eager_load(:bought_diamonds).last.bought_diamonds.count
# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'scope_caches.snapshot_date' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `diamonds` INNER JOIN `scopes` ON `diamonds`.`scope_id` = `scopes`.`id` WHERE `scopes`.`id` = 34 AND (diamonds.created_at >= DATE_SUB(scope_caches.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and diamonds.created_at < scope_caches.snapshot_date)

ScopeCache.preload(:bought_diamonds).last
# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'diamonds.created_at' in 'where clause': SELECT `scopes`.* FROM `scopes`  WHERE `scopes`.`id` IN (34) AND (diamonds.created_at >= DATE_SUB(scope_caches.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and diamonds.created_at < scope_caches.snapshot_date)
```

**Option 2:**

```
has_many :bought_diamonds,  :through => :scope,  :conditions => proc { "diamonds.created_at >= #{self.snapshot_date-1.week} AND diamonds.created_at < #{self.snapshot_date}" }
```

Problems:

```
ScopeCache.includes(:bought_diamonds).last
# NoMethodError: undefined method `snapshot_date' for #<Class:0x0055b073211398>

ScopeCache.eager_load(:bought_diamonds).last
# NoMethodError: undefined method `snapshot_date' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinAssociation...

ScopeCache.preload(:bought_diamonds).last
# NoMethodError: undefined method `snapshot_date' for #<Class:0x0055b073211398>
```

I also tried

```
has_many :bought_diamonds, class_name: "Diamond", :foreign_key => "scope_id", :primary_key => "scope_id", conditions: proc{['diamonds.created_at >= DATE_SUB(scope_caches.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and diamonds.created_at < scope_caches.snapshot_date']}
```

with problems similar to option 2

Comment: In a similar manner, I'd like an association `:previous_cache` on the same table with `scope_caches.snapshot_date` being `self.snapshot_date - 1.week` but it does not work either. One thing I have observed is that many of these associations print out "(Object doesn't support #inspect)"

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you really using Ruby on Rails 3.2? A Rails version that is 10 years old?

Comment: @spickermann given the `:conditions` key I would say yes.

Comment: @spickermann sadly, yes I am